# Why are my two navbar-right elements overlapping?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have two *navbar* elements that are intended to be side by side using the `navbar-right` class from bootstrap. Bootstrap takes care of the spacing rather well when I use it on just the `ul`. However, when I try to float a `div` to the right, and then float the `ul` to the right, I wind up with some overlap.

Here are images of what I am talking about:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "main-nav-collapse">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <% if current_user %>
      <%= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn" %>"
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn", method: :get %>
      <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-success navbar-btn", method: :get %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", new_contact_path %></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Any suggestions on overcoming this? I can add in CSS to toy with the margins, but it seems like this is something that Bootstrap should be able to handle on its own?

Comment: You should first take the time to add your **HTML output** in a Snippet so others have a working example of your code, Ruby isn't useful in this instance. See [mcve].

Comment: Fixed code highlighting, removed bold font-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a single navbar-right and put the code you want inside of it.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "main-nav-collapse">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <% if current_user %>
      <%= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn" %>"
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn", method: :get %>
      <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-success navbar-btn", method: :get %>
    <% end %>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", new_contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Aaron